# Conversion of URL string to Dict in python 2.7

Tags: python

I have string like

```
s='www.gmail.com?uname=mark&pwd=test&age=20'
```

and i want string(s) to be converted into dict(d) in following manner

```
d={'uname':'mark','pwd':'test','age':20}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 12):

BTW fix your URL. But here is the answer:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
>>> url = 'www.gmail.com?uname=mark&pwd=test&age=20'
>>> urlparse(url).query
'uname=mark&pwd=test&age=20'
>>> parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)
{'age': ['20'], 'pwd': ['test'], 'uname': ['mark']}
```